# Magento Child Theme Creation Problem

Tags: parent-child-theme, theme-fallback

I've a fresh installation of Magento ver 1.9.1.0 on localhost. I'm following [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee114-ce19-rwd-dev-guide) closely to create a child theme of Magento responsive theme.

I've followed all steps clearly. I've created Magento directory structure, using this approach

```
[Magento Directory]/app/design/frontend/{package_name}/{theme_name}/etc
```

and created theme.xml file there. As can be seen 
[image]

Exact location of the theme.xml file is:

```
[Magento Directory]/app/design/frontend/tutsplus/vstyle/etc
```

as my package name is 'tutsplus' and theme name is 'vstyle'. I've also correctly enabled this theme from admin panel. As can be seen in below screenshot:

[image]

The code of theme.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>
```

Can someone point out what am I missing?

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't have idea how do?

Answer (score 1):

Your screenshot from the design tab in the configuration is not complete. Setting `vstyle` only under the templates section is not enough. You have to define it under templates, skin and layout or just under default.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks good. Did you clear the Magento cache? Any change to XML files requires the cache to be cleared.

Comment: All cache is already disabled, still I've flushed Magento cache, but to no avail. Page still appears broken with no css styles.

Comment: On the tutorial I'm following it is written:

 If styles.css is loading from a path similar to the following, theme.xml is most likely not loading.

`http://www.example.com/magento/skin/frontend/base/default/css/styles.css`

This is precisely the problem I'm facing